# How to link to a specific answer?

Tags: support, interface

Is there a way to link directly to a specific answer? I can't see an obvious way but perhaps I'm overlooking the functionality.

If this doesn't exist, it would be a "nice to have" on the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup - just click the "share" link below the answer - you'll get a permalink to that answer.

Comment: Perfect. This is what I needed, just wasn't seeing the link for some reason!

Comment: Me neither - "share" seems like the wrong verb, as I expect it to only contain social media links. A "permalink" link would be clearer.

Comment: Agreed. I'll open a question with that suggested change.

Comment: Also not obvious...but you can link to comments, too. Just click the time stamp text that follows the commenter's name and then grab the URL.